# Encapsulating `sort` Interface in Golang

Tags: go, encapsulation

I am trying to sort a slice of structs in Go. I can implement the `sort.Interface` by defining 3 methods at the top level of the package:

```
type byName []*Foo // struct Foo is defined in another package

func (a byName) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a byName) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a byName) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i].Name < a[j].Name }

func Bar() {
    var foos []*Foo // Populated by a call to an outside function

    sort.Sort(byName(foos))
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to move the 3 method definitions (`Len`, `Swap`, and `Less`) into the `Bar` function, defining an anonymous method in Go?

```
// Something like this
func Bar() {
    ...
    Len := func (a byName)() int { return len(a) }
}
```

Can the 3 methods defined at the top level be accessed from outside of this package? I am guessing not, because the type `byName` is local.

Comment: the fully-qualified name of `Len` is `packagename.byName.Len`. As you say, since `byName` isn't exportable, `Len` isn't visible to an outside package either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, no, there are no such things as anonymous methods in Go.

As anonymous functions cannot be declared using a receiver, they are effectively not methods, therefore the `byName` type would not implement the required `sort.Interface`.

Comment: Oh well. I was hoping to "hide" the definitions, but I guess since they are local only, that will have to suffice.